# Why is this code valid? Assigning before declaring?

Tags: java, initialization

This is Java. I understand that the assignment of 1 to `index` is in an `initialization block` that is first run when the class is instantiated, but why is this valid?

```
public class arr {
    {
        index = 1;
    }

    int index;

    void go() {
        System.out.println(++index);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
          new arr().go(); 
        }
    }
```

Output is 2.

I should be getting a `symbol not found` compilation error. Is this behaviour native to initialization blocks? In a *normal* scenario `int index;` should come before `index = 1;`.

Comment: Good question... I knew `static` initializers were valid (ie, as in your program, except `index` is static and the code block is also preceded by the `static` keyword) but not that.

Comment: Look in the Java Language Specification, and try to find a rule that this breaks - you won't find one. Compare that with the rules for *local* variables though, and things should become clearer...

Comment: OP didn't specify how this relate to Java.

Comment: @Mob tags are not persistent, should retag or you do it in the question?

Comment: @RomanC The tags and `System.out.println`?

Comment: @Mob do it in the question that you use the Java language not Coffee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1, it looks really weird. But as a matter of fact non-static initialization blocks are simply inserted by javac into object constructors. If we decompile arr.class we will get the real code as

```
public class arr {
    int index;

    public arr() {
        index = 1;
    }

    void go() {
        System.out.println(++index);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new arr()).go();
    }

}
```

to make more fun of consider this puzzle

```
public class A {
    int index;

    A() {
        index = 2;
    }

    {
        index = 1;
    }
}
```

what is new A().index ?. Correct answer is 2. See decompiled A.class

```
class A {
    int index;

    A() {
        index = 1;
        index = 2;
    }
}
```

that is, non-static initialization blocks come first in object constructors

Comment: Correct. Non-static initialization blocks are frequently used in lieu of constructors (see JMock's Expectation)

Answer (score 4):

Non-static initialization blocks run right after the constructor so the code is correct and the output as expected.

Comment: But there's no constructor. . . Am I missing something?

Comment: There's an implicit constructor derived from java.lang.Object

Comment: A default constructor is added to every java class, that does not contain a constructor.

Comment: @Mob there is always a no-argument, default constructor if none is declared

Comment: Okay, yes I know about the compilers business with adding constructors, but I am lost on this, which runs first the init block or the assignment and why?

Comment: You can always experiment: set `index` to 2 when declared and see what happens ;)

Comment: I think I get it now, but would have appreciated a proper breakdown! Thanks.

Comment: See Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer, it is very detailed.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what order the code is in.  As you state,

> In a normal scenario int index; should come before index = 1;

This is exactly what happens the field is declared and then the value 1 is assigned.  The compiler does not care about the physical ordering of these items in the class.

Answer (score 2):

From [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Here is an example of using a final method for initializing an instance variable:

```
    class Whatever {
        private varType myVar = initializeInstanceVariable();

        protected final varType initializeInstanceVariable() {

            // initialization code goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) states:

> A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body.

Furthermore it is the same with variables, which you can "use" before they are declared:

```
class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new T();
        System.out.println(t.a);
    }

    public int a = 14;
}
```

Comment: The user is referring to a non-static initialization block, not a static one.

Comment: I missed this part, thanks. However the tutorial further states: "Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword", so it seems the conclusion stays the same.

Comment: Just to clarify things, their positions in the execution order would be different.

Comment: A life without static initializers much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some languages (e.g. C), the order of *declaration* of class (static) variables and instance variables is not relevant in Java.  You can refer to an class / instance variable (textually) before it has been declared.  So even this is valid ...

```
public class X {
   private int a = b;
   private int b = a;
   ...
}
```

... though the initializers don't actually achieve anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Java is such a language that fully parses your code before performing any stunt with it (I'm trying to avoid boring compiler details). So it doesn't matter if your initializer block comes before the declaration of the field, there is a specific order in which things take place. Class loading (and of course field loading), static initializers, constructors, non-static initializers are all run before any method call (static invokations can be performed without the execution of constructors and non-static members).
You should consider reading some SCJP (now OCPJP) books like "K & B" to really know what's going on under the hood. A tutorial like "JVM internals" might be an overkill at this stage (but you should consider keeping it in your archive for later referencing).